# can't convert a sys.argv strings to int

Tags: python, int, sys

I run my code.py with  [path/to/working_directory] [filename] [number of particles] for example:

```
python2 code.py /home/user/file thing.txt 100
```

They all come in as strings understandably. I cannot get the [number of particles] to convert to int. The code looks something like:

```
import math, scipy, numpy ...ect
import ConfigParser
import sys


def main():
    working_dir = sys.argv[1]
    filename = sys.argv[2]
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        filename = filename[:-4]   #removes '.txt' extension

    number_parts = int((sys.argv[3]))
```

I get the following error at this stage:

> "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"

Floats work but I need an integer. I've tried:

```
number_parts = int(float(sys.argv[3]))
```

even:

```
temp = float(sys.argv[3])
ignore, number_parts = modf(temp)
number_parts = int(number_parts)
```

any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your imports for an identifier clash.

Are you importing a module called int?

Comment: thanks, yes one of my other functions files was calling scipy.integrate as int.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether any `int` is imported.Check this also(whether `builtin int` is overriding)

```
>>>type(int)
<type 'type'>
>>>callable(int)
True
```

OR

```
from __builtin__ import int
number_parts = int((sys.argv[3]))
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped my figure out I was overriding the builtin

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the error happens in this line? Could you provide the whole stacktrace of the error? I'm asking because you import your libraries in a way there shouldn't be any namespace confusions (as opposed to importing with `from ... import *`).

Also, I would remove the extra brackets in `int((sys.argv[3]))` (or are you using it as a tuple later on?) and change it to `int(sys.argv[3])`.

For me, this works when I call it with the same command you used:

```
import math, scipy, numpy
import ConfigParser
import sys

def main():
    working_dir = sys.argv[1]
    filename = sys.argv[2]
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        filename = filename[:-4]   # removes '.txt' extension

    number_parts = int(sys.argv[3])
    print number_parts

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

which will print `100`. Can you check if this minimal example works for you (to narrow it down)?